# Open Office \ Microsoft Word compatibility problems with paragraph directions

Tags: microsoft-word, libreoffice-writer, docx, hebrew, odt

I'm trying to use Open Office (specifically, I tested LibreOffice 3.3) for writing documents, which should be shared with MS Word users.
This documents include Hebrew text, that uses right to left paragraphs (RTL).

both word processors support RTL, but when creating a document in Open Office, and opening it with MS Word (2007, 2010), the paragraph direction doesn't transfer well (some paragraph appear OK, some appear in the wrong direction).

The other direction works fine (Open Office reads correctly the paragraph direction specified by MS Word)

This happens both for docx (Word) documents, and for odt (Open Office) documents.

Any ideas \ workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried **[IBM's Symphony](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/lotus/symphony/home.nsf/home)**?